# GMail - waiting for the page for fully loaded

Tags: selenium, automation, automated-tests, robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to automate gmail page (for some kind of email verification), after input username and password, I want to wait the page to fully loaded before continuing to my next action.

This is what I tried:

```
Selenium2Library.Input Text    //input[contains(@id, "identifierId")]    ${local_email_username}
Selenium2Library.Click Element    //span[text()="Berikutnya"]
Sleep    2s
Selenium2Library.Wait Until Element Is Visible    //input[contains(@name, "password")]    timeout=30s
Selenium2Library.Input Password    //input[contains(@name, "password")]    ${local_email_password}
Selenium2Library.Click Element    //span[text()="Berikutnya"]
Sleep    2s
Selenium2Library.Wait Until Element Is Visible    //input[contains(@aria-label, "Search")]    timeout=30s
### should be logged in to gmail
Log    >>> logged in to gmail. sleeping..
Sleep    5s
### make sure the email page fully loaded
Log    >>> making sure the email page fully loaded.. waiting new conversation button appeared
Comment    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    10x    2s    Selenium2Library.Page Should Contain    ${email_name}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    20x    3s    Selenium2Library.Page Should Contain Element    //button[contains(@title, 'New conversation')]
Log    >>> email page fully loaded. start searching activation email...
```

What I want to achieve is waiting for the new conversation button, that indicates that page is fully loaded `(//button[contains(@title, 'New conversation')])`

The problem is the script never finds the button. I tried to inspect and search for that xpath, and the element found.

Is there any solution for that?

**Update:** 
i tried using Select Frame like this.. like @Gaurav said.. here's the code:|

```
Selenium2Library.Select Frame    ${iframe_locator}
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    20x    3s    Selenium2Library.Page Should Contain Element    //button[contains(@title, 'New conversation')]
Selenium2Library.Unselect Frame
```

where ${iframe_locator} is `//body/div[7]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/iframe[2]`

but still no luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is in iFrame, so you need to switch to that iFrame(there might be more iframes, so you need to switch to that specific one) and the look for `//button[contains(@title, 'New conversation')]`

Here is Corresponding Java Implementation

```
    @Test
    public void newConversation() throws IOException, InterruptedException{
         driver.get("https://www.google.com/intl/hi/gmail/about/");
         driver.findElement(By.linkText("प्रवेश करें")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.id("identifierId")).sendKeys("*********@gmail.com");
         driver.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
         Thread.sleep(30000);
         driver.switchTo().frame(5);
         WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@aria-label,'Change profile picture')]"));
         Actions action = new Actions(driver);
         action.moveToElement(element).build().perform();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(@title,'New conversation')]")).click();
    }
```

Comment: it has no text 'New conversation' btw

Comment: @thekucays...oh! the problem is this button is in iframe, let me update my answer

Comment: @thekucays..will you please try, I'm going for lunch

Comment: sorry for late response.. i've updated my question.. could you please take a look a bit? :D

Comment: could you please try on your machine using your own google? i think the gmail main page would be the same if you use the default theme of course :D

Comment: I've updated my answer with working Java implementation, convert accordingly